# Facebook like button, when clicking like work then doesnt

Tags: facebook, xfbml

so im struggling, I got a page with few facebook things on it, http://www.simplyshows.com/watch-csi-new-york/Season-1-Episode-1/blink/ when you click the like button it likes it, reloads, and shows as if you havent liked it.. been playing around for an hour now, nothing helped, anyone could help me out?

Current code im using:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=106063289489162&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="<?= "http://www.simplyshows.com/" . $s->episode_url($episode_data['episode_id']); ?>" send="false" layout="box_count" width="60" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also seen such refreshing. But, my friend the like button is working fine for me. have a look below:

[image]

Comment: ya.. sometimes i too have faced similar situation. i think it has something to do with session and cookie management.